# Calculation repeating text in multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to calculate how many times the word "yes" occurs in a specific column on several individual sheets all within the same spead sheet. I can use =COUNTIF(range,"*yes*") which works for the first sheet but if I try and add another sheet/s it tells me "youve entered too many arguments for this function". Any ideas

Comment: What specific formula give the error "too many arguments..." Maybe you just have a typo, range should be able to be expressed with a sheet! preface.

Comment: This is the formula i tried, =COUNTIF('Leighton Jenkins'!I2:I10000,'Lucy Hutchinson'!I2:I10000,'Darren Howarth'!I2:I10000,'Scott Kerr'!I2:I10000,'Christopher Highfield'!I2:I1000,'Claire Young'!I2:I10000,"*yes*"). I am new to this and this is a project for work so forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIF` only takes one range. You get the desired result by summing up multiple `COUNTIF`s:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(range1,"yes"),COUNTIF(range2,"yes"),COUNTIF(range3,"yes))
```

I would put the criterium into a cell and refer to it in the formulas, this keeps it tidy.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, this formula worked a treat. I'll be in touch with the next one :-)